# How to check active and queued jobs count in the Play Framework?

Tags: playframework

My app must report its job load via HTTP API. The "play status" command seems to give the info I need:

```
Jobs execution pool:
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Pool size: 0
Active count: 0
Scheduled task count: 0
Queue size: 0
```

How to access this info in a Play Framework *controller*?

Comment: Do you know what is the equivalent of "play status" in Play 2.x ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at JobsPlugin.java, there's a static executor property, the getStatus() method shows where the values come from:
https://github.com/playframework/play/blob/master/framework/src/play/jobs/JobsPlugin.java

```
    out.println("Jobs execution pool:");
    out.println("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");
    out.println("Pool size: " + JobsPlugin.executor.getPoolSize());
    out.println("Active count: " + JobsPlugin.executor.getActiveCount());
    out.println("Scheduled task count: " + JobsPlugin.executor.getTaskCount());
    out.println("Queue size: " + JobsPlugin.executor.getQueue().size());
```